# Take PHP Session out to display a website in Swift

Tags: php, ios, session, authentication, uiwebview

So I've start building an application for a website in Swift. The main goal is to have an iOS App which can receive notifications (in JSON from website) and can show all the features of the website.
So I can login and sign-up from the app to my database but the thing is I don't understand how to take out my session login and display it in an UIWebView. So the user has just to log-in and he can see the website with his account. The only thing I can make is to show the website as a guest.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Do you have a code sample of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Kmeixner : Hi, yes sure but the code is soooo long and it's just to get "login" and "password" in PHP & Swift variables, I can't display everything here. But now I don't know what I can do to display a website with a session (in something like UIWebView) ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know UIWebView does not store/send any cookie(session) for your web site. That means you're always not authenticated.

In order to complete your task you need to create your own cookie handling mechanism.

1. You need to save auth cookies sent to you by the server in response HTTP header, e.g.

   `Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABAD1D;`
2. Then you need to make any required request and MANUALLY put cookie header filed in your request header e.g.

   `Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABAD1D`
3. Save response somewhere and render HTML in a WebView

BOTTOM LINE: All this stuff is a huge overhead to your app. Instead you need to write API of your web-site specifically for iOS(and other) apps, using different authentication approach and data transfer (well known).

What you want to do is basically create a little browser, I don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. Wow it seems very complicated to do such thing. I was thinking that it was easier. I don't understand how people are doing an iOS App for a Website ? Are they creating again everything and just put request from website database ?

Comment: Not actually to database, but to API of your web-project. We also use local database, usually we make a design with different screens and UI idioms which are specfic for iOS, though it can have similiar style with your web part. Since you have local database and amazing graphical UI from iOS, using an app of that kind is much and much nicely than a  website on mobile device. Plus you have less traffic.